# Kill sbt in windows powershell

Tags: powershell, sbt

I'm running `sbt` on Windows using `powershell`.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to kill sbt.  One example of when I want to do this is if I forget to set my proxy settings.  If I forget to set them, sbt usually hangs for 30 seconds or more when trying to resolve each dependency.  If there are a bunch of dependencies, it takes a while to wait for them all to fail.

If this was `cygwin` or `bash`, I'm pretty sure `ctrl+c` would work, but it appears to have no effect in powershell. I've also tried `ctrl+break` which appears to give a thread dump, but doesn't stop the process. I can go to the task manager and search for the process and kill it, but I'm hoping there's an easier way, also it's not always obvious which process I should kill from the task manager.

I've also tried `ctrl+z`, `ctrl+d` and a bunch of others that don't seem to do much.  I'm guessing this is more of a powershell issue with not passing through the signal, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: How are you launching it from Powershell?

Comment: A better alternative to the task manager in this case is Process Explorer: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx With this you can see the full command line of the process.

Comment: Why can we not find sbt.exe or whatever and stop it by $PID ?   `Get-Process sbt | ForEach-Object -Process {Stop-Process -Id $_.ID}` Tell me the name of the executable we are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Powershell are you using? For me, `Ctrl+C` while running sbt resulted in a prompt `Terminate batch job (Y/N)?` which terminated sbt when I entered `Y`. This worked both with the standard terminal and ConEmu, so it's odd that it does not work for you.

Running sbt does not result in a process named `sbt`, but rather one named `java`, since scala runs under the JVM. For this reason, you have to inspect the command line args of the process to see if it is sbt. You can add a CommandLine property to the results of Get-Process:

```
Update-TypeData -TypeName System.Diagnostics.Process -MemberName CommandLine -MemberType ScriptProperty -ea silent -Value { $id = $this.Id; $result = Get-WmiObject win32_process -Filter "ProcessId = $id"; $result.CommandLine };
```

...which will allow you to enter the following in a different Powershell window to kill sbt:

```
ps java | ? commandline -m "sbt" | kill
```

Alternatively, you can use Powershell from within a different terminal, such as ConEmu (my favorite) or Console2, which gives you an option to terminate the currently-running process in any given terminal window/tab.